# Terminal loses transparency with theme

Tags: drivers, themes, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome, transparency

I'm kinda new to Linux but I'm a fast learner and experienced IT. Anyway, I recently did a dual boot on my system (Windows 10 / Ubuntu) and I'm using gnome as my DE. Everything works very well except for 1 thing. When I'm using the default theme (using the Gnome Tweak Tool) everything works fine.

But when I try using any other themes, my terminal loses its transparency. If I go to preference (terminal's preference) and "Uncheck/Check" the use dark theme option, the transparency comes back. However, if I close the terminal and open it again, the transparency is gone again. This is a little annoying and I would like to find a solution.

I'm thinking it might be a video driver issue, I'm using an AMD R9 390. I tried all the 3 available driver. The open source driver, and both proprietary driver from AMD. I tried 3 different theme just in case the bug was caused by the theme itself. (I'm using GDM by the way)

Any help would be much appreciated! I know it's not that important but it's still bugging me. Thanks in advance!

itSp4x

Comment: And which theme do you mean?

Comment: I've tried the foolowing themes:
Ceti-2 http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ceti-2+-+Theme?content=167528
Vertex http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Vertex+-+Theme?content=166318
Viva: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/viva-3.14+%28orange%2Bblue%29?content=167066

Comment: In this case you should ask the developer of the theme.

Comment: The problem occurs with every themes I try, so I doubt the issue is caused by the theme itself....

Comment: You have GNOME 3.16?

Comment: Same problem here, ok =) Also with other themes. But not with Adwaita :\

Comment: GNOME Shell 3.14.4

Comment: And yes, with Adwaita it works just fine for me too (which is the default theme of gnome)